# How can I change the Hidden Attribute of a file/folder? (Alternative to attrib FILENAME -h)

Tags: command-line, gui, alternative

On a MS Based system (Windows, any versions) You can use the `attrib` command in order to change the attributes on a specified file, directory or directory with recursively changing the files inside the directory also, the command may look like:

```
attrib FOLDERNAME -s -r -a -h /S /D
```

Which will remove any attributes to a specified FOLDERNAME including the files/folders inside of it.

When a Virus modifies these attributes to the files/folders in a removable device (USB/SD Memory/HDD) in order to hidden them from the user, I use my Ubuntu OS Based computer and plug the device in the appropriate slot and I can see all the files/folders and manually remove the undesired items on the device. But I am in need to run to a MS OS Based computer/laptop in order to change the attributes via command line (`cmd`) and this way, "bring back" the items visible to the rest of the people.

Ubuntu is having the ability to change the file properties via GUI or `chmod`, but I haven't found a way yet to remove the `hidden` (`attrib -h`) attribute in a file/folder.

Is it there a way to do this? No matters if is a GUI or Terminal

Comment: So you want to remove the `hidden` permissions on Windows files from Ubuntu? (thing is hidden files in Ubuntu begin with a `.` ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind: yes, I couldn't say it better. But my problem is that Windows machines won't see hidden files that can be seen in Ubuntu without a hassle. Thank you.

Comment: ntfs? fat? ....

Comment: MS Based systems seems not to have problems about the File System itself. Any information will be appreciated as an answer but thanks for asking. I have both NTFS and FAT File Systems on different devices, suffering of the same issue constantly.

Comment: ok half an answer for now: fat. I can not find anything related to NTFS yet.edit: I do not think you can do ntfs... hope I am proven wrong by someone else ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [fatattr](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fatattr) [image: Install fatattr] if the disc is `vfat`.

> FAT filesystems contain several attributes which do not map cleanly onto Unix attributes; this utility allow these to be controlled directly by unprivileged users on any mounted FAT partition.

Syntax is

```
fatattr [+-hsra] [files]
```

The letters are...

```
h hidden
s system
r read only
a archive
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! This is working like a charm on FAT FS. I really appreciate a lot your help. Now let's expect somebody comes soon to drop us a NTFS solution, meanwhile, your answer is for me which solved my problem for FAT's. Thank you very much!